# Access the same data a textbox in the XAML is bound to

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm

WPF MVVM in ViewModel I want to access the same data a textbox in the XAML is bound to

The XAML on MainWindow.xaml has a textbox bound to StoredProcs/ProcName

```
<TextBox Name="txtProcName" Text="{Binding Path=StoredProcs/ProcName}"></TextBox>
```

And a Grid bound to StoredProcs
Whenever the grid selection changes, the bound text in the textbox changes as it should.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Height="300" Width="290"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    Name="dataGrid1" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding StoredProcs}" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
    Margin="-6,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Proc Name" Binding="{Binding ProcName}" >
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have a button that executes a procedure in MainWindowViewModel when clicked, that works

```
<Button Content="Create RDL" Command="{Binding CreateStoredProcedure}" />
```

In the CreateStoredProcedure code, I need to access the same data that is displayed in the textbox (not using code behind). I would think I need to get the StoredProcs/ProcName but can't figure out how to do that.

I tried adding CommandParameter to the XAML but don't know how to access it in the CreateStoredProcedure instructions as it won't allow me to add paramaters

```
void CreateStoredProcedureExecute()
{
    string procName = "proc";
    //procName = { StoredProcs/ProcName };
    MessageBoxResult result = 
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Create Stored Procedure {0}", procName));
}

bool CanCreateStoredProcedure()
{
    return true;
}

public ICommand CreateStoredProcedure 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return new RelayCommand(CreateStoredProcedureExecute, 
            CanCreateStoredProcedure); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you not just pass the data in the CommandParameter property of the Button? CommandParameter={Binding Path=StoredProcs/ProcName}

Comment: Are you saying I would do this?
string useProcName = {Binding Path=StoredProcs/ProcName}
?

Comment: No sorry, in the xaml declaration for the Button you can add the CommandBinding parameter just like you add the Command parameter, in the Execute method of the command you'll have access to the parameter.

Comment: @DavidBeck I added some extra info in my answer, hopefully it solves your new issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, you should be able to get the value of the property that the TextBox is bound to from within CreateStoredProcedure.

One thing though, if you want the TextBox to update the property, make sure you add "Mode=TwoWay" to your binding expression:

```
<TextBox Name="txtProcName" Text="{Binding Path=StoredProcs/ProcName, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood I think you want something like this?

```
<Button 
  Content="Create RDL" 
  Command="{Binding CreateStoredProcedure}" 
  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=txtProcName, Path=Text}"/>
```

However as the other answer states, you should be able to just access the property in the ViewModel that is backing the textbox from the command, but if for some reason you cannot my code should work as well.

(Assuming you are defining RelayCommand as defined by [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) MSDN article, this should fix your other problem)

```
public ICommand CreateStoredProcedure 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return new RelayCommand<object>(
            (object parameter) => CreateStoredProcedureExecute(parameter), 
            (object parameter) => CanCreateStoredProcedure); 
    } 
}


private void CreateStoredProcedureExecute(object parameter)
{
    string ProcName = parameter as string;
}
```

I will admit my somewhat inexperience with setting up commands like this, but I did find a working example in my code that followed this, so hopefully it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure how to incorporate your changes here
void CreateStoredProcedureExecute()
        {
            string procName = "proc";
            procName = e.Parameter as string;
            //procName = { StoredProcs/ProcName };
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Create Stored Procedure {0}", procName));
        }

        bool CanCreateStoredProcedure()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public ICommand CreateStoredProcedure { get { return new RelayCommand(CreateStoredProcedureExecute, CanCreateStoredProcedure); } }

Comment: @DavidBeck Please edit your question instead of trying to put lots of code into a comment

Comment: @KDTraglia Almost I have the message "the non-generic type 'RDLfromSP.RelayComand' cannot be used with type arguments.

Comment: Make sure you have the RelayCommand class implemented like that MSDN article, it should have a constructor that accepts the generic.

Comment: @KDTraglia - i pasted it from the MSDN site (see above)

Comment: Wow, this is far too difficult. I can bind from the XAML, it would seem that I could access the same thing from the MainWindowViewModel.CreateStoredProcedure. The path in the XAML is StoredProcedures/ProcName so I would hope I could access the same thing from the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I think KDiTraglia has the right solution. The only thing I would do differently is to bind the `CommandParameter` to the model, not the UI element.

```
<Button 
     Content="Create RDL"
     Command="{Binding CreateStoredProcedure}" 
     CommandParameter="{Binding Path=StoredProcs/ProcName}" />
```

I'm assuming that `StoredProcs/ProcName` is a placeholder for a real, valid binding path.

Root around here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308

Comment: he does declare `CreateStoredProcedure` as an `ICommand`, he is just returning an inherited type.